# Permits in mysql installation data folder keep changing (OS X) and I cannot access the database

Tags: mysql, osx-yosemite, file-permissions

I'm having a big issue with my MySQL installation.

I set the ownership of my /usr/local/mysql/data folder to _mysql:_mysql user, nevertheless, after a few minutes, it changes by itself to root:admin.

Apparently there is something that is changing the ownership and the permissions of my file, but I cannot figure out what is it.

I set it to:

```
drwxr-x---  17 _mysql  _mysql    578 May 19 15:28 data
```

but then it changes again to:

```
drwxr-x---  18 root  admin    612 May 19 15:34 data
```

Of course, this makes my DDBB unuseful as I cannot perform any queries.

I have tried to uninstall and install again several times, in different ways (using the .dmg file and homebrew), cleaning every folder I find related to mysql, etc. but i cannot solve it.

Just after the installation everything looks to work fine, but after a few minutes the permissions are corrupted again.

I'm using

```
sudo chown -R _mysql:_mysql /usr/local/mysql*/data
```

to change the permits. Is this the right way?

Anybody has experienced the same problem? How can it be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo chown -RL mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/data
```

Comment: It made no difference.